# Coordinates outside the map frame in Layout doesn`t show - am I missing something or it`s a bug?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, layouts

Trying to get coordinate grid around my map in Layout. Like this: [image: sample], grid across map is not necessary, only the marks along edge.

All the settings seem to be correct according to suggestions online, still, the coordinates outside map frame just doesn`t show. Screenshots of my settings:
[image: Settings1]
[image: Settings2]

Please help! What`s wrong? Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Using Qgis 3.16.8-Hannover on Win 10.

Comment: Your interval is 0

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks a lot! Awesome!